# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection refused

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

My API and `EndToEndTests` are in two diffrent containers, when I build the docker-compose.yml, I am getting connection refused exception.

**Failed**

`PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests.Test.ValueControllerTest.Get_AllValues_ReturnsTrue`

```
| Error Message:
|  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection refused
| ---- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused
| Stack Trace:
|    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
|    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
|    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
|    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
```

Below are my docker(API and End2End), docker-compose.yml and appsetting.json files:

**API docker**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.csproj Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/
RUN dotnet restore Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue
RUN dotnet build PagingSystem.MessageQueue.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish PagingSystem.MessageQueue.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PagingSystem.MessageQueue.dll"]
```

**End2End Test docker**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk AS build
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

WORKDIR /src

# copying
COPY Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.csproj Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/
COPY Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests.csproj Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests/
COPY Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.UnitTests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.UnitTests.csproj Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.UnitTests/

#restore 
RUN dotnet restore Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.csproj
RUN dotnet restore Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests.csproj
RUN dotnet restore Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.UnitTests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.UnitTests.csproj

#copy rest
COPY . .

#build
WORKDIR /src/Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app
CMD ["sh", "-c", "sleep 1m && dotnet test -c Release -o /app"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  pagingsystem.messagequeue:
    container_name: pagingsystem-messagequeue-container
    image: pagingsystemmessagequeue
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Source/PagingSystem.MessageQueue/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:80
      - 5002:443
    networks: 
       - xyz-network

 pagingsystem.messagequeue.endtoendtest:
    container_name: e2e-test-container
    image: pagingsystem.messagequeueendtoendtest
    ports:
      - 5011:80
      - 5003:443
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Tests/PagingSystem.MessageQueue.EndToEndTests/Dockerfile
    networks:  
      - xyz-network

networks:
  xyz-network:
    driver: "bridge"
```

**appsetting.json**

```
 {
      "MessageQueueApi": {
        "Url": "http://pagingsystem-messagequeue-container:5000/"
 }
```

**BaseTest.cs:**

```
public class BaseTest : IDisposable
    {
        public BaseTest()
        {
            var appSettings = AppSettings.Current;
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
            };
            this.HttpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = appSettings.MessageQueueApi.Url,

            };
            Console.WriteLine("<---API URL is --->" + appSettings.MessageQueueApi.Url);

            Console.WriteLine("---Base address");
            Console.WriteLine(this.HttpClient.BaseAddress);
        }

        public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

        public List<string> AllValues { get; set; }

        public void Dispose() => this.HttpClient.Dispose();

        protected async Task GetAllValues()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----in get all values---");
            var response  = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync("api/values");
            response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);         
        }

    protected Task<HttpResponseMessage> ClearCache() =>
        this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("cache/clear", string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are mismatching the `HOST_PORT` and `CONTAINER_PORT`.

For `5000:80`, `5000` is `HOST_PORT` and `80` is `CONTAINER_PORT`. While accessing the container from container, Networked service-to-service communication use the `CONTAINER_PORT`.

Try to change `"Url": "http://pagingsystem-messagequeue-container:5000/"` to `"Url": "http://pagingsystem-messagequeue-container:80/"`

Comment: Thanks Tao Zhou ! I have tried using "http://pagingsystem-messagequeue-container:80" URI, now I am getting " System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Resource temporarily unavailable" error.

Comment: @SudarshanGaikwad When did you get this error? If you access the web api directly from web browser with `5000` port, will it be accessable?

Comment: Zhos, its accessible from web browser with 5000 port, but it fails when "e2e-test-container" hits "pagingsystem-messagequeue-container".  As I said in above comment, when I use "http://pagingsystem-messagequeue-container:80/" URI in appsettings.json, it gives "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Resource temporarily unavailable" error

Comment: @SudarshanGaikwad Share us the code related with sending request from e2e test project.

Comment: @ Tao Zhou, I have added "BaseTest.cs". Its end2end project's file from where  API gets hit. If this file is not enough, I will add a demo project on github.

Comment: @SudarshanGaikwad I would suggest share us the demo

Comment: @SudarshanGaikwad: did you solve this problem , i am facing this too?